# iPhone - Image overlay MapKit framework?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I can see with iOS4 you can now tile an image on google maps (Been looking at the TileMap example from apple). This is great as this is what I want to do, but from what I can see I need to know the GEO reference of the image so I can raster the images with the appropriate zoom levels, etc. What I have is an artist image, which is a map of a specific area and I want to overlay this image on google maps.

Am I missing something here, but can this be done with a none standard map and having different zoom levels?

The main reason why I need to use google maps is because of the GPS functionality, so the user will know where they currently are on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Georeferencing is how you "pin" your image to the world. It is a tricky process, but not too hard once you dig into it.

You've already found the TileMap example code - that is the first step.

Next, check out MapTiler.org.  There you will find links and some binaries that you can use to process your image into georeferenced tiles.

If you don't know the lat/long coordinates for your image, you can use Google Earth to interactively overlay the image onto the map, and then copy the coordinates out.

Good luck!