# MonoTouch Mapkit image overlay

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have been looking for a good tutorial on adding an image overlay for Mapkit in C# Monotouch.

I have found many overlay examples for coloured circles or polygons. But I want to load a PNG over the top of my maps. I am coming from MonoAndroid and have done it there, but need to transfer my program across to iOS.

Even a objective C example would help, but Mono would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up downloading some native objective C code and pretty much just converting it into C#. The function names are very similar, the Xamarin API references Documentation is very helpful.

There where some tricky bumps I ran into around the app delegate, and how it is handled differently in C# to Objective C.

Here are the two hardest functions to convert and my solution:

1) The Draw functions in the map overlay class

```
    public override void DrawMapRect (MKMapRect mapRect, float zoomScale, CGContext ctx)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(
            () => 
            {
            UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(@"indigo_eiffel_blog.png");

                DrawImgRotated(image, 0, ctx);
            }
        );
    }

    public void DrawImgRotated(UIImage image, float rotDegree, CGContext c)
    {
        c.SaveState();

        CGImage imageRef = image.CGImage; 

        //loading and setting the image
        MKMapRect theMapRect = ((MapOverlay)this.Overlay).BoundingMapRect;//MKMapRect theMapRect    = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
        RectangleF theRect = RectForMapRect(theMapRect);

        //we need to flip and reposition the image
        c.ScaleCTM( 1.0f, -1.0f);
        c.TranslateCTM(-theRect.Width/8,-theRect.Height);

        // Proper rotation about a point
        var m = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(-theRect.Width/2,-theRect.Height/2);
        m.Multiply( CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(rotDegree)));
        m.Multiply( CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(theRect.Width/2,theRect.Height/2));
        c.ConcatCTM( m );

        c.DrawImage(theRect, imageRef);

        c.RestoreState();
    }
```

and 2) the bounding mapRect function in my mapOverlay class overriding MKOverlay.
Yes the position is hardcoded, I am working on unit conversion atm but those are the correct coordinates to draw the image same as in the sample obejctive c code I used.

```
    public MKMapRect BoundingMapRect
    {
        [Export("boundingMapRect")]
        get 
        {
            var bounds = new MKMapRect(1.35928e+08, 9.23456e+07,17890.57, 26860.05);
            return bounds; 
        }

    }
```

The source code for the Objective C project I converted is here: https://github.com/indigotech/Blog-MKMapOverlayView

Xamarin API reference documentation: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to go about this will depend on the kind of image you want to overlay. If it’s just pretty small, you should be able to get away with just using a single image. However, if it covers a larger area that uses expect to be able to zoom in on, you may have to split it up into separate tiles for better performance.

Here’s some other questions on Stack Overflow that might answer it for you:

[How do I create an image overlay and add to MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283741/how-do-i-create-an-image-overlay-and-add-to-mkmapview)

[iPhone - Image overlay MapKit framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436368/iphone-image-overlay-mapkit-framework)

See Apple’s WWDC2010 sample code TileMap
https://github.com/klokantech/Apple-WWDC10-TileMap (posted to GitHub by someone)

None of this has anything to do with Mono, but you should be able to convert it…