# Adding images to mkmapview Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I had found this post on the site for adding UIImage to the MKMapView but this is in the objective-c. can any body help how can we use it on the monotouch by c# ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6554418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you to view this screencast from Xamarin about **["Developing iOS Map Applications with C#"](http://docs.xamarin.com/videos/ios/developing-ios-map-applications-c)**.
It doesn't cover the custom MKOverlayView drawing part because it's exactly as creating a custom view and overriding it's drawing routine.
But it does explain you how and why you have to endup here..

Basically, you have to

- create a custom MKImageOverlay object (subclassing MKOverlay)
- create a custom MKImageOverlayView object (subclassing MKOverlayView) that will handle the actual image drawing methods (like any view drawing overriding using CoreGraphics)
- add your custom MKImageOverlay to the map with MKMapView.addOverlay() method
- provide a MKMapViewDelegate to the map that will handle your custom MKImageOverlay by overriding GetViewForOverlay and returning your custom MKImageOverlayView

You could look at this SO post here too : [MonoTouch Mapkit image overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207660/monotouch-mapkit-image-overlay)

Cheers